# What is the difference between Jeppesen NavData & Digital Terminal Charts?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, software, jeppesen

https://ww2.jeppesen.com/update-cycle-and-effective-dates-schedule/

in the link provided above,
Jeppesen NavData has 28day cycle whereas
Digital Terminal Charts have 14day cycle
Can you provide the reason for varying update cycles

i am aware by the name Terminal charts means airports information and approach plates, SIDs & STARs but what does NavData contain ?

Answer (score 0):

Terminal charts are published per a 14-day cycle which is usual in IFR chart circulation.

Jeppesen states on their [website](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/navigation-solutions/navdata/?gclid=Cj0KCQjw37iTBhCWARIsACBt1IyxcRHC9sQarytk82vhuF7QiROwOOTvvz25Tw6Rpdsjtu5xT98ALzUaApTEEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) that the NavData pack is published according to the 28-day AIRAC cycle.

The NavData pack contains navigational charts, terrain/obstacle data, and data for RNP/LPV.

Comment: I will respectfully disagree. The AIRAC cycle is 28 days, which is a worldwide standard. Jepp chooses to publish charts every 14 days, which allows them to update a chart instead of issuing a NOTAM. However, procedures are updated on the normal AIRAC cycle which includes both the chart and data.

Comment: Agree with Timbo. That's an option they chose. Ivanantuns is right too, regarding the service content.
You use Digital Terminal Charts on your iPad or a Windows device, and NavData is loaded into FMS.